# Is it now wrong to "return" from a "switch" statement in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012, I noticed that a `switch` that's been working for several years now seems to be broken in Release builds but works correctly (or at least as it used to) in Debug builds. I can't see anything at all wrong with the code so would appreciate some feedback on the correctness of using `return` statements from within a `switch` block.

The following code compiles ok but gives the wrong output in a Release build on Win7 32-bit...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

class CSomeClass
{
public:
    float GetFloat(int nInt)
    {
        printf("GetFloat() - entered\n");
        switch (nInt)
        {
        case 1 :
            printf("GetFloat() - case 1 entered\n");
            return 0.5F;
        case 0 :
            printf("GetFloat() - case 0 entered\n");
            return 1.0F;
        case 2 :
            printf("GetFloat() - case 2 entered\n");
            return 2.0F;
        case 3 :
            printf("GetFloat() - case 3 entered\n");
            return 3.0F;
        case 4 :
            printf("GetFloat() - case 4 entered\n");
            return 4.0F;
        }
        printf("GetFloat() - exit\n");
        return 1.0F;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CSomeClass pClass;
    float fValue = pClass.GetFloat(3);
    printf("fValue = %f\n", fValue);

    return 0;
}
```

If you can repeat the problem, and have a MS Connect login, maybe you can vote it up here too?

**Actual results**

Release build gives the following incorrect result:

```
GetFloat() - entered
GetFloat() - case 3 entered
fValue = 0.000000
```

**Expected results**

Debug build gives the following correct result:

```
GetFloat() - entered
GetFloat() - case 3 entered
fValue = 3.000000
```

[MS Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779043/c-switch-statement-broken-in-release-build#details)

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are seeing?

Comment: What is the *wrong* and *desired* output? .

Comment: Works fine for me (OS X 10.7, clang++). No surprise Microsoft made a buggy toolchain.

Comment: C++ will never make it an error to return from a switch case. That would break like 80% of all software ever written.

Comment: @meagar - only 80%? It'd be about 98% of all code I've written - the remainder probably doesn't use switch or return in the same function, so should be OK.

Comment: Well I'll be, looks like a bug alright!

Comment: @MatsPetersson I was being conservative :p

Comment: I've edited in the results from the user's bug report.

Comment: Here's [**assembly comparison**](http://pastebin.com/ZregiQyY). Used `cout`, but results are similar.

Comment: `std::cout << pClass.GetFloat(3);` giving the output **0**. Not sure why.

Comment: can you provide a disassembly of the release build? I am sure that your use of `return` is standard conform. It must be a bug on the compiler side.

Comment: A 64bit build has the expected result, the optimizer is screwing something up. Going from /O2 to /O1 gives correct results again on 32bit, so yeah, bug.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz your pastebin link is missing the disassembly of the function `GetFloat`.

Comment: did u contact the support directly?... not sure how urgent, but its a totally broke thing

Comment: Looking at the disassembly window in VS2012, there is some bad mix of FPU and SSE2 going on. Yeah, that looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: @example Running it through debugger really shows no error in `GetFloat` - it chooses the right `return`.

Comment: Thanks everyone - looks like a definite MS compiler bug then! As others have found, 64-bit runs fine and so does 32-bit with optimisations disabled. Will have to figure out how this affects our massive codebase now .....

Comment: @user2065121: you can try compiling with `/arch:IA32`, it makes the compiler generate working code, by disabling all SSE stuff. Explicitly enabling SSE through `/arch:SSE` and above also seems to be a fix.

Comment: @user2065121 Right now it seems that `/O1` is the way to go.

Comment: FYI Intel C++ 13 (which is thankfully the compiler I use with VS!) does not exhibit this bug either

Comment: @Fanael - thanks for that tip - using /arch:IA32 does the trick and also explains why our legacy projects converted from VS2008 all work ok - the SSE/SSE2 default changed with VS2012 (VS2010?) so now you get it for "free" - better off without IMHO.

Comment: Roger,  I have upvoted the issue on ms connect, and there I also make the comment that the problem also occurs in non-member functions, as can be checked by lifting your GetFloat() function out of the class, and removing the definition and reference to the class altogether.

Comment: This is... astounding.

Comment: @Josh - thanks, I saw your comment and have edited my post on connect accordingly - strange that I did similar but got a good result, maybe because I had other bits of the old code around it optimised differently. The /arch:IA32 suggestion by Fanael seems to indicate something broken in SSE as hvd suggested earlier.

Comment: The minimal set of options to repro the problem seems to be: `cl /GL  /O2 /MD /arch:SSE2 test.cpp`.  Link time code generation (`/GL`), optimization level 2 (`/O2`) and you have to link to the msvcrt.dll library (`/MD`). `/arch:SSE2` is the default setting in VS2012.  Linking to the static runtime library (`/MT` - the default) prevents the problem for some reason. Changing any of those four options works around the bug (at least for this particular example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like it might be [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768562/visual-c-11-produces-bad-assembly-code-when-using-whole-program-optimization-for-x86-target#details)? Where there is a problem in returning floating point values generated in a similar way?

Comment: Yep - that sounds like the same thing - certainly the example is almost exactly the same as mine... so this has been around for a few months already!

Comment: At least they said they'll fix it in a future release. I wonder if it's fixed in the recent update they did with some more of c++11?

Comment: @jcoder: If you mean that November CTP, that was not an update. It's a community tech preview; known to not be production ready and only released for testing and feedback. Once they deem it ready, then it may become available as an official update.

Comment: Sorry yes I understand that it's not by any means a production release, I just wondered if it fixed this bug as that would be a good sign for a timely release of a fix.

Comment: This answer lost its meaning due to the link no longer linking to a valid page.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely a compiler error. Here is the stripped down asm code being executed (jumps etc. removed). The compiler removes some code it assumes to be unnecessary - even though it is not.

---

Release build:

```
// inside GetFloat
00E0104D  fld         dword ptr ds:[0E021D8h]  // load constant float onto FPU stack
00E01068  add         esp,4
00E0106B  ret 
// back in main
00E01098  cvtss2sd    xmm0,xmm0  // convert float to double. assumes the returned value to be in xmm0
00E0109C  sub         esp,8  
00E0109F  movsd       mmword ptr [esp],xmm0  // push double being printed (xmm0 is with high likelyhood = 0)
00E010A4  push        0E021B8h   // push output string
00E010A9  call        dword ptr ds:[0E02090h]  // call printf
```

---

Debug build:

```
003314B0  fld         dword ptr ds:[335964h]   // load const float onto FPU stack
[...]
00331500  mov         esp,ebp  
00331502  pop         ebp  
00331503  ret         4  
// back in main
00331598  fstp        dword ptr [fValue]  // copies topmost element of the FPU stack to [fValue]
0033159B  cvtss2sd    xmm0,dword ptr [fValue] // correctly takes returned value (now inside [fValue] for conversion to double 
003315A0  mov         esi,esp  
003315A2  sub         esp,8  
003315A5  movsd       mmword ptr [esp],xmm0  // push double being printed
003315AA  push        335940h  // push output string
003315AF  call        dword ptr ds:[3392C8h]  // call printf
```

Answer (score 5):

Gathering data from all the results, it's most probably compiler bug.

- x64 works correctly
- `/O1` works correctly
- well, `Debug` works correctly
- it gives the same kind of error on both `cout` and `printf`

And, probably the most important - it's 100% standards compliant. So it *should* work.

Comment: having the same results... freaky

Comment: That is a *terrible* bug, though.

Comment: I am not touching VS compiler with a 10 foot stick from now on.